# C++ Memory Management diffrences with Heap Allocation and Frame Allocation

Tags: c++

I am slightly confused about how memory management works in C++, I understand when you use pointers (new/delete) but I'm lost when it comes to Frame allocation.

Say I have a simple class (Using QT Classes)

```
class Demo {
    public:
        Demo();
        ~Demo();
        QString AString() const;
        void setAString(const QString &value);
    private:
        QString aString;
};
```

And I Allocate it using a pointer

```
Demo *testInst = new Demo();
```

Now I understand when i call "delete testInst;" That is freed, but I'm confused about the out of scope part on Frame Allocations. Does that mean when I call delete, all those in the class that are not pointers are automatically freed, or do i have to do specific memory management within the deconstructor of the Demo class? Or does it mean if I leave the class those variables are freed?

I'm new to C++ and came from a .NET background so I'm not 100% understanding of manual memory management.

Comment: Where did you find the term 'frame allocation'? There's no sign of anything except the normal heap above.

Comment: I think its a term more used in MFC, so sorry if i didnt get the right definition, Im doing things in Qt so I'm just wondering how does the non pointer objects (QString) work in memory compared to pointer objects (QString *) do I need to do anything manually to free them or does deleting the pointer object delete ones not allocated using new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two allocation disciplines in C++. Heap and Stack. I'm suspecting that you mean Stack when you write 'frame'. Sometimes, especially in old C sources, it's called 'auto'.

```
Demo localDemo;
```

is how you would use the stack. Before executing the next statement after this, C++ promises to create a temporary object of type `Demo` and call the no-args constructor. After the last statement in the current `{}` lexical block that references `localDemo`, C++ promises to call the destructor and release the storage. The storage is, in fact, part of the stack frame of the procedure or block.

A related question is a data member of class type. If you write:

```
class Proletariat {
   private:
      Demo localDemo;
};
```

Then the automatically-generated constructor for `Proletariat` will call the `Demo` constructor, and the the destructor will always call the `Demo` destructor.

If you have a constructor with args, you write something like:

```
class Proletariat {
   private:
      Demo localDemo;
   public:
      Proletariat() : localDemo("omeD") {}
}
```

to pass those args.

```
};
```

Comment: So if its contained in a class, would that object last for the life of the class (If done as a private variable) until i call the object's destructor using delete?

Comment: That's a different matter altogether. Edit coming.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to understand C++ Mem Management.

Answer (score 0):

In plain C++ you are generally going to need a `delete` for every `new` (oversimplification, I know) that is in your code.

In the example above you need to do no further memory management other than calling `delete` as have already shown.  If your class had member variables that were allocated on the heap (for example, aString was a QString* that you had `new`'d in your constructor, then in your destructor you would also need to delete it.